# iOS UITextView keeps scrolling to bottom automatically when I scroll from bottom to top

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview

I create an iOS project, which contains only one UITextView full of the whole screen.
And in the controller, I do the things like below

```
//textView is declared in the .h file which keeps a reference to the UITextView
textView.text = @"";//a long text(over 5000 words), and contains many '\n'
if(textView.text.length > 0) {
    NSRange bottom = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 1);
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:bottom];
}
```

the textView display a very long text, which will contains 5000 words or more and the text contains many '\n'.

Then I run the project on the simulator iOS 7.0, and scroll from bottom to top. And then the UITextView keeps scrolling to bottom automatically. 
Please help me. I have stuck in this problem for a long time.

Comment: What is the problem here. You are giving the range for bottom. so it should do the way of scroll to bottom only.

Comment: scroll from bottom to top : **NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);**

Comment: The textView scrolls to bottom when it shows the first time, which is what I need. But then I can't scroll to top by hand.

Comment: may be the above lines of code are executed all the time when you try to scroll either to top or bottom. so it always scroll to bottom, check in your scrollView delegate methods that you are not writing above code.

Comment: I don't have any delegate methods. And I debug the project, finding that the code above executes only once. And if the long text doesn't contain '\n', it will work fine and the problem will disappear.